# Laravel Route Model Binding Return False Owner of The Post

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-models

Good morning/afternoon/evening!

I have 2 model, User and post

User.php

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'user_name';
}

public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'by_id', 'id');
}
```

> I have two records in users table

```
|--------------------------------------------|
|   id   |   user_name   |   ...   |   ...   |
|--------------------------------------------|
|   1    |   megamanx    |   ...   |   ...   |  
|   2    |   black_zero  |   ...   |   ...   | // Edited
```

Post.php

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}

public function by()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'by_id', 'id');
}
```

> I have one record in posts table

```
|----------------------------------------------------|
|   id   |   by_id   |   slug              |   ...   |
|----------------------------------------------------|
|   1    |   1       |   test-first-post   |   ...   |
```

In my route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{user}', function () {

    Route::get('/', function (User $user) {
        return View::make('user.index', compact('user'));
    });

    Route::get('/{post}', function (User $user, Post $post) {
        return View::make('post.index', compact('user', 'post'));
    });
});
```

As you can see I use Route model binding for User `user_name` and for Post `slug`

So when I visit the route, ex :

```
127.0.0.1:8000/megamanx/test-first-post
// it return the correct owner
```

> user megamanx is the owner of the post (test-first-post)

But, when I try the user param to other user, ex :

```
127.0.0.1:8000/black_zero/test-first-post
// Hey you don't own that post!
```

> And the owner post name change to black_zero, **but he didn't own that post**

So how to solve this? I want when the user try to change the `user_name`, to something else, return 404. because only user `megamanx` own post `test-first-post`

> I'm always open to critics, cause I want to be a better developer, if there's any wrong in method above (Route, model, etc), please correct me!, thank you (・∀・)ノ

Sorry for bad english (￣▽￣*)ゞ

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to create `laravel policy` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#writing-policies

Comment: Both users have same id.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Tpojka sorry my typo, black_zero id is 2

Comment: @lagbox, I'm using L7.25

Comment: @Kamlesh how do I implement that? Is policy able to do things like that? I thought policy only for CRUD Authorization #LaravelNewbieHere

Comment: Your code breaks lot of Laravel standard and good practice, naming convention etc. First you should do is to check [nested resources](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-nested-resources) in documentation. Also, my advice would be to go through good practice [here](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices) for writing code in Laravel.

Comment: @Tpojka I see, thank you for guiding me, I just started learning laravel 3 months ago

Comment: If you follow docs and naming convention from docs and from github link I linked here, you'll avoid more than 50% unforced errors. Like table names, column names, primary key, foreign key names, classes names too etc. For concrete issue check Gate and Policy in docs.

Comment: @tpojka i still dont get how to implement policy for my question, since my english is not really good, could you give me a hint?

Comment: You haven't make any restriction to prevent showing non-user's post. Check gate and policies how can you achieve that.